# How to start in TDD with Ruby?

Tags: ruby, tdd

I want to know your recomendations to begin with TDD in Ruby (not Rails), so that's it, I know a little about what TDD is, but I'm looking to which tool to use for this, do you know any tutorial for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I learned Ruby using [Ruby koans](http://rubykoans.com/), and they are an awesome way to learn Ruby with TDD. But never ignore RSPEC.

- Read this: [How to get started on TDD with Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386562/how-to-get-started-on-tdd-with-ruby-on-rails)
  This covers Rails, but the idea is same. TDD.

Comment: as I read, is recommendable just start with Unit Test, thank for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen [rspec](http://rspec.info/)?  It's behavior-driven (which is ever so slightly different from test-driven) but the main point is that you write your tests first and it constantly runs them and provides feedback (using autospec in a separate window) while you write your code.