# TDD concept in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, cucumber, capybara

I have doubt about my understanding of TDD concept in RoR.
This is how I get it:

1. Module tests have to be done with rspec:

1.1. Controllers - checking:

a) correctness of variables assigns

b) correctness of response

Should we call here the Model's methods (stubs)?

1.2. Models - checking:

a) precense of ActiveRecord's method calling when we call model's method

b) correctness of model's methods calculations

1.3. Views - checking:

a) precense of some information on the page?

Should I make these tests if I'll make cucumber+capybara integration tests?

1.4. Requests - checking:

a) precense of DOM elements?

Should I make these tests if I'll make cucumber+capybara integration tests?

1.5. Routing - checking:

a) precense and correctness of routes

2. Integration\acceptance tests have to be done with cucumber+capybara.

It may cross with rspec tests.

Should we call rpec's tests (according to DRY principle) in that case? And how?

Give me the feedback please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386562/how-to-get-started-on-tdd-with-ruby-on-rails) 
may help you with it. You fill find a lot of useful links here about TDD and RoR. I hope it is what you are looking for.