# Book/Tutorial for TDD/BDD in ruby?

Tags: ruby, tdd, bdd

I write ruby but want to start with TDD/BDD for a new project. IS there any tutorial or good books out there for learning TDD/BDD.

Comment: Related and might be useful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1386562/how-to-get-started-on-tdd-with-ruby-on-rails

Comment: TDD by example (by Kent beck) is one of the best books i know for TDD. But examples are in Java though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the books mentioned above peepcode screencast on cucumber and rspec is also good.

Links 
[cucumber](https://peepcode.com/products/cucumber) and [rspec](https://peepcode.com/products/rspec-basics)

Answer (score 4):

I really liked this one: [The RSpec Book: Behaviour-Driven Development with RSpec, Cucumber, and Friends](http://pragprog.com/book/achbd/the-rspec-book).

Answer (score 2):

[The Cucumber Book](http://pragprog.com/book/hwcuc/the-cucumber-book) is a great book, which although small doesn't miss out on anything you'll need to know about BDD using Cucumber and Ruby. I'd also highly recommend [Growing Object Oriented Software](http://www.growing-object-oriented-software.com/).

Answer (score 1):

All the previous answers were centered in the **technology behind TDD/BDD** (i.e. rspec).

If you are looking for a way to see/understand the **process as a whole** I really enjoyed [Rails 3 in Action](http://manning.com/katz/), because it TDDs a whole application.

It is easy to follow and quite mind-opening! :)