# Where to start test Driven Development in iOS7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, tdd, xcode5

I'm new to iOS development and want to learn Test Driven Development. Didn't find any good resource to start with. I searched and came across this . . [Where to start with test driven development?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18747251/where-to-start-with-test-driven-development)

which is only for ruby on rails.

I'd appreciate if anybody guide me where to start with.

Comment: See http://qualitycoding.org/tdd

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading documentation on testing from Rails world actually is not a bad idea. TDD is seen as really important within the Rails world. Some key concepts are explained better there than in the iOs world in my opion.
The answer of Riyazul has some nice links. I also like these:

NSHipster has this [post](http://nshipster.com/unit-testing/) about unit testing.

From the Ruby world [this](http://www.rubymotion.com/developer-center/articles/testing/) article about testing in Ruby motion is interesting. Everything can also be done from Xcode.